# How to optimize the query to update a table column with a column in another table in SQL windows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below query and it take 9 hours to complete.
Any help to decrease the time?

```
update tableA set tableA.id = ( select   top 1 b.id 
                                from  tableB b  
                                where tableA.bin = b.bin );
```

Comment: TOP looks more like sql server

Comment: Please do not tag multiple RDBMS. I have removed the Oracle tag as `TOP` is not valid syntax for Oracle.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; details of any indexes or constraints; the execution plan for your query; and anything else relevant to the performance of the query. At the moment the question is too general to be able to make any specific suggestions.

Comment: There can be multiple matches in tableB and you don't care which of these you use to update tableA? Then your query is probably as fast as it gets. There should be an index on tableB(bin) or even a covering index on tableB(bin, id) in order to quickly find a matching tableB row..

Comment: Without knowing anything like number of rows, table structures, what fields are indexed... everyone is just going to guess what might help.

Comment: MySQL does not have `TOP` either.  Perhaps you need sql_server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the following query might do what you want

```
update tableA
set tableA.id = b.id
from tableB b 
   where
        tableA.bin = b.bin
```